# Windows Server 2016, Remote Desktop with lowest resolution\colors possibility

Tags: remote-desktop

My IT job includes working remotely to vessels via VSAT connection. Because this is sattelie, speed and latency are issues. For vessels equipped with Windows Server 2008 R2 or even Server 2003 Ican manage just fine. I can connect with just 256 colors and the system is usable.

I have sent newer servers to some of vessels with Windows 2016 or 2019. Whatever method I have tried though I still cannot achieve RDP with lower that 32 bit color. Even changing configs doesn't help.

I mostly use Devolutions RDP manager.

Has anyone been able to connect to Windows Server 2016 or 2019 using the lowest possible color depth?

Comment: Everything I've read suggests that anything below 15-bit colour is unsupported by all modern operating systems and RDP v8 or above. I sympathise with your situation, but I'm not seeing a solution besides running the regular `mstsc`, setting the experience to 56k and crossing your fingers.